# Restoring deleted markers on google maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a map with a number of markers and I have nearly implemented a kind οf filter on the map. When I click on the markers, the markers disappear and a button shows up to the top of the map to restore the markers-this is what is not functional. I tried to re-create the markers when the user clicks on the button, but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas? Here is my code:

```
 function getCrimeByLocation(lat, lng, date){
if(date == null){
    var d = new Date();
    date = d.getFullYear() + '-' + (d.getMonth()+1);
    //hardcoding as of now as jan 2014 data is not there, remove when req
    date = "2013-02";
}
$.getJSON( "http://data.police.uk/api/crimes-street/all-crime?lat="+lat+"&lng="+lng+"&date="+date, function( data ) {
    while(markers.length > 0){
        markers.pop().setMap(null);
    }

    //marking the requested position
    addMyPositionMarker(lat, lng);
    //loop through the data
    $.each(data, function( key, val ) {
        //var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(val.location.latitude, val.location.longitude);
        //create the markers on the map
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(val.location.latitude, val.location.longitude),
            map: map,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            draggable: false,
            title: val.location.street.name
        });
        markers.push(marker); // saving markers for reference, so that we can remove them later;
        //'click' event to delete the markers from the map
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){
            for(var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++){
                markers[i].setMap(null);
            }
            markers.length = 0;
            //Once the markers are deleted, the button shows up
            antisocial.show();
        });
    });

    var antisocial = $('<button>Anti-social behaviour</button>').hide().click(function(){
        //Here I tried to restore the markers, but it doesn't work
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(val.location.latitude, val.location.longitude),
            map: map,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            draggable: false,
            title: val.location.street.name 
        });
        markers.push(marker);
        //hide the button once it's clicked
        antisocial.hide();
    });
    $('#map-canvas').before(antisocial);

    if(markers.length > 0){
        fitBoundsMap();
    }
});
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to set the map to null to hide the markers and reset the map back to the original map to show them again.

Comment: Thank for your answer. I have set the map to null when I created the `click` event on the markers and that works fine. Also the button shows up to the top. To display them again, I tried to re-create the markers and also the `setMap(markers)`, but non of these are working.

Comment: There's no need to recreate them, they should still exist, just set their map back how it was.

Comment: Still don't get it. You mean with `markers.push(marker)`?

Comment: I think he means to loop through your markers array (which still exists) and do a `marker[i].setMap(map)` on each marker.

Comment: @MrUpsidown Yes, that is exactly what I meant.

Comment: Thank you guys :) The thing is that I tried what @MrUpsidown said before I post my code here, but finally the actual bug was the following: I defined `markers.length = 0;` after my for-loop and from then, the length of the array was permanently zero. Hence, the array didn't have enough markers to display when the button was clicked. Thanks for your inputs and effort though :)